# Showing notification popup in excel

Tags: excel, vba

Is there a way to show a notification popup to users every 5 minute in excel through VBA or anything else?all i want to do is showing a message(reminder)  automatically to users to save their works every 5 min.

Comment: Please take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
Sub my_Procedure()
    MsgBox "Save your workbook!"
    Call test ' for starting timer again
End Sub

Sub test()
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:05:00"), "my_Procedure"
End Sub
```

To automate this macro, put this code into ThisWorkbook:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
   Call my_Procedure
End Sub
```

Instructions [here](http://analysistabs.com/excel-vba/run-macro-automatically-opening-workbook/)

!!! Be careful about automatization, just put some if condition to run popup code, otherwise this code may run decpite you close shared workbook.

Comment: thank u.amazing.can i use it on a shared workbook also?i make this vba and after that change the workbook to shared?

Comment: I don't actually know. Please read this article: http://www.exceladvisor.net/51/excel-shared-workbook